# Freebase query result buried under nonsense

Tags: freebase

A beginner's question about freebase:

I am looking for the imdb id of a movie called "O". If I use the searchbox on the freebase.com website and constrain the search by type to `all:/film/film`, then I get a high quality result with the best match on top:

http://www.freebase.com/search?query=o&lang=en&all=%2Ffilm%2Ffilm&scoring=entity&prefixed=true

But this does not include the imdb id. When I try to recreate and refine this search using the query editor, I can't figure out how to do a "general query". The best I could come up with was doing a fuzzy name search like this:

```json
[{
  "type": "/film/film",
  "name": null,
  "name~=": "o",
  "imdb_id": [],
  "rottentomatoes_id": []
}]
```

The result contains exactly the information I want, but the movie "O" is only the 12th result in the list, buried under lots of nonsense:

[http://www.freebase.com/query?lang=%2Flang%2Fen&q=[{%22type%22%3A%22%2Ffilm%2Ffilm%22%2C%22name%22%3Anull%2C%22name~%3D%22%3A%22o%22%2C%22imdb_id%22%3A[]%2C%22rottentomatoes_id%22%3A[]}]](http://www.freebase.com/query?lang=/lang/en&q=%5B%7B%22type%22%3a%22/film/film%22,%22name%22%3anull,%22name~=%22%3a%22o%22,%22imdb_id%22%3a%5B%5D,%22rottentomatoes_id%22%3a%5B%5D%7D%5D)

How can I improve the quality of my result? What special magic does the "?query=o" use that `"name~=":"o"` does not have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `query=o`, freebase does some smart sorting of the results, display exact matches first, followed by less exact matches.

With your query `name ~= o` you are not searching for movies with name "O", but for movies that contain "O" in their names (the `~=` operator). If you want to search for a specific movie title, then specify the exact name:

```json
[{
  "type": "/film/film",
  "name": "o",
  "imdb_id": [],
  "rottentomatoes_id": []
}]
```

This will result in output:

```json
{
  "result": [{
    "imdb_id": [
      "tt0184791"
    ],
    "name": "O",
    "type": "/film/film",
    "rottentomatoes_id": [
      "o"
    ]
  }]
}
```

Comment: My apologies, I just realized I asked my question not very well: I need to query with a certain fuzzyness. The example I gave was not the best, I will look for a better one... In any case, thank you for pointing out that ~= means "contains", not "fuzzy match", as I had incorrectly assumed.

Comment: @MartinJ.H. It's not exactly 'contains' but instead 'matches'.  `name ~= o` is the same as regex matching name against `o` - effectively doing 'contains'.

Comment: Not really. "name~=":"o" matches topics with the *word* "o" in them.  If you wanted a true contains, you'd need "*o*" (which would probably time out).  Also, search weights results by popularity, which MQL doesn't do.

Answer (score 0):

If Search gives you the topic that you want, why not just use the [`output` parameter](https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/search-output) to add the IMDB ID (or whatever else you want) to the output that you request it return?

Comment: Can you give an example on how to use the output parameter?

Comment: There are a large number of examples on documentation page  I've added a link since it apparently isn't findable using Google.